# Goto\Jump in Python

Tags: python, goto

I'm coding a text game in python 3.4 and when I though about making a save game came the question:

How can I jump to the place that the player stopped?

I'm making a simple game, me and my friends, so I just wanna jump to a certain part of the code, and I can't do that without having to make around 15 copies of the code, so can I jump to a line?

Comment: This question is super broad; what do you mean by `jump to the place that the player stopped?` Do you mean like a save file? write your game state to a file of your choice and load into it. Do you mean `jump to the place that the player stopped?` as in what line in the code they reached and you want them to go back to it like a questionaire?

Comment: "Goto Considered Harmful" long before Python appeared: http://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the overall structure of your program.  Your game should be controlled by a main loop that handles user interaction, and the game state should be contained in a small number of objects.  You can then use `pickle` or some other data persistence mechanism to save the state and reload it, and you simply enter your main loop again.

Comment: My code is simple, it's more like a history, so if the player stopped on certain point I wanna just jump the previous part and start from that point.

Comment: Thanks Sven Marnach I'll try to learn more about it, I'm new to codding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using something like [python-goto](https://github.com/snoack/python-goto) but this is a very bad idea.

In python, you don't have really any reason to do a goto.

A way better way would be to save the structure containing your data with something like [pickle](https://github.com/snoack/python-goto) and loading it back when the user want to restart the game.

For instance:

```
import pickle

game_data = {'something': [1, 2, 3 ]}

pickle.dump(game_data, open('file.bin', 'wb')
```

Then, you can load the data back:

```
import pickle

game_data = pickle.load(open('file.bin', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `goto` built into Python. There are ways to effectively 'halt' in a method by using yield and creating a generator, which is effectively how Python coroutines work (see the `asyncio` module) however this isn't really appropriate for your needs.

For saving game state, saving and serialising the state you need to resume the gameplay in a more general way is a much better idea. You could use `pickle` For this serialisation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the game-state as something that you can assign a value (or values) to. If this is a very simple text game, then the player will have a location, and that location will presumably be something you can "jump" to via use of a reference.

Let's say your code follows this pseudo-code pattern:

```
 start
     player_location = 0
     print_start_game_text()
     begin loop:
         display_text_for_location[player_location]
         display_options_for_location[player_location]
         player_location = parse_player_response(response_options_for_location[player_location])
         if isGameEndCondition(player_location):
             break;
     print_end_game_text()
 end
```

This pattern would reference some data files that, for each location provided some collection such as      `1, "you are in a room, doors are [E]ast and [W]est. You can [S]ave your game, or [L]oad a previously saved one", { "E" : 3, "W" : 2, "S" : "savegame", "L" : "loadgame" }`

Then using a function to display some options, collecting the users response and parsing that data, returning a single value; the next location. You then have a new key to reference the next element in the data-file.

IF your game is as simple as this, then your save file need only contain a single reference, the player's location! Simple.

If you have objects that the player can manipulate, then you'll need to figure out a way to keep track of those, their locations, or state-values - it all depends on what your game does, and how it's played.

You should be thinking along these program vs data lines though, as it will make the game much easier to design, and later, extend, since all you'd have to do to create a new adventure, or level, is provide a new datafile.